# How do I make it so it asks and then print depending on the answer?

Tags: python

I have this, what do I need to implement to make it ask me which conversion I want?

```py
def user_choice(Celsius to Fahrenheit, Fahrenheit to Celsius):
    return input ('Which conversion do you want to do? ')
```

I've tried a lot of combinations but can't seem to fit it right

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: What are `Celsius to Fahrenheit` and `Fahrenheit to Celsius` supposed to be?  As it stands, this is invalid syntax.

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2):

I need more info about the vars. But you first need to name to var,
to make it usable, and put something like:

```
Var1 = input('Which conversion do you want to do? (Press A for Cº or B for Fº)')
```

then some conditional like:

```
if Var1 == "A":
```

Then you do you calculations and when you finish, you do it again but with

```
elif Var1 == "B":
```

And you do your results
Once you have them to print you do:

```
Var2 = print(Put the variable where the results are without the "")
```

then you return it like this

```
return Var2
```

Comment: Okay yes, so I have the formula for the conversion, only need to know how to make it  like :
The conversion c to f press A, or the conversion f to c press B
then if u press a it says "enter Celsius"
and then it calculates it

Comment: See the edited message (If you don't see it, is because i'm still editing)

Comment: @CharlesKrylander I have written the whole program with a small explanation below if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to ask if the user wants to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celsius. This can be done by defining a variable which stores this decision. You could store it as a number, 1 or 2. 1 could be Celsius to Fahrenheit and 2 could be Fahrenheit to Celsius. This can be done with the following code.

```
user_choice = input("Which conversion? Celsius to Fahrenheit = 1, Fahrenheit to Celsius = 2\n")

if user_choice == 1:  # Celsius to Fahrenheit
    # conversion code

elif user_choice == 2:  # Fahrenheit to Celsius
    # conversion code
```

For the conversions, you would want to take an input of what the user wants converted and then use a method for converting. This might look like this.

```
user_choice = input("Which conversion? Celsius to Fahrenheit = 1, Fahrenheit to Celsius = 2\n")

if user_choice == 1:  # Celsius to Fahrenheit
    user_input = input("What temperature would you like converted to Fahrenheit?\n")
    converted_temp = (user_input * 1.8) + 32
    print(f"Your converted temperature is {converted_temp}")

elif user_choice == 2:  # Fahrenheit to Celsius
    user_input = input("What temperature would you like converted to Celsius?\n")
    converted_temp = (user_input - 32) * 0.5556
    print(f"Your converted temperature is {converted_temp}")
```

Here, I just used the conversion formula google gave me.
I hope this helps you!

EDIT:
Here is the fixed code.

```
user_choice = int(input("Which conversion? Celsius to Fahrenheit = 1, Fahrenheit to Celsius = 2\n"))

if user_choice == 1:  # Celsius to Fahrenheit
    user_input = int(input("What temperature would you like converted to Fahrenheit?\n"))
    converted_temp = (user_input * 1.8) + 32
    print(f"Your converted temperature is {converted_temp}")

elif user_choice == 2:  # Fahrenheit to Celsius
    user_input = int(input("What temperature would you like converted to Celsius?\n"))
    converted_temp = (user_input - 32) * 0.5556
    print(f"Your converted temperature is {converted_temp}")
else:
    print("That is not a valid input.")
```

Comment: Yes, now I put some of it in, butt get a error on this : elif user_choice == 1: input('Enter a temperature in Celsius : ')

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I have fixed the code in the edit.